# Optimizing the search of a powerset

Tags: python, performance, optimization

I have some code that finds all the combinations of items (under a size limit, in this case 8) that match some criteria, but it gets far too slow after a collection size of about 20 items. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
import timeit

def powerset(iterable, n):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    mx = min(len(s), n)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, mx+1))

collection = [
    (0, 10, "item1"),
    (5, 5,  "item2"),
    (10, 0, "item3"),
]
targetA = 5
targetB = 5

def build():
    output = []
    for s in powerset(collection, 8):
        a, b = (0, 0)
        for item in s:
            a += item[0]
            b += item[1]
        if a >= targetA and b >= targetB:
            output.append(s)
    return output

print(timeit.timeit('build()', number=100, globals=globals()))
```

My original code uses classes for items, and has a larger collection, and needs to be able to search for values both greater-than or less-than an arbitrary value. I know that this is just a brute-force search (I think this is `O(n!)` or close to it), but is there any way that it can be optimized? Right now I am just looking for some basic ideas while also learning about algorithmic complexity, so any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write your own recursive function and pass the target values as parameters. This way, you can determine the amount missing and the max amount achievable with the remaining items and stop early in case no combination is possible anymore.

```
def combs_with_sum(collection, num, targetA, targetB):
    def _inner(i, n, s):
        # found a valid combination with n elements?
        sum_a = sum(c[0] for c in s)
        sum_b = sum(c[1] for c in s)
        if n == 0 and sum_a >= targetA and sum_b >= targetB:
            yield s

        # more elements to go and still valid solutions?
        max_a = sum(sorted(c[0] for c in collection[i:])[-n:])
        max_b = sum(sorted(c[1] for c in collection[i:])[-n:])
        if n > 0 and i < len(collection) and sum_a + max_a >= targetA and sum_b + max_b >= targetB:

            # combinations without and with the current element
            yield from _inner(i+1, n,   s)
            yield from _inner(i+1, n-1, s + [collection[i]])

    return (x for n in range(1, num+1) for x in _inner(0, n, []))
```

Here, `sum_a >= targetA and sum_b >= targetB` makes sure that only valid results are yielded, and `sum_a + max_a >= targetA and sum_b + max_b >= targetB` prevents infeasible combinations from being searched. This will slice, sort, and again slice the collection in each turn to find the maximum sum achieveable with the remaining elements, but this prevents a great deal of branches from being searched. (The `sum_a` and `sum_b` values could also be passed down as parameters, but that should not matter much.) For the "less-than"-case just invert the `>=` to `<=` and reverse the sort to get the sum of the `n` smallest remaining items.

Applied to some random test data:

```
from random import randint, seed
seed(0)
collection = [(randint(1, 10), randint(1, 10), i) for i in range(20)]
print(collection)
res = list(combs_with_sum(collection, 4, 30, 30))
```

This will call the `_inner` function < 1,000 times, as opposed to > 15,000 times without the `sum_a + max_a ...` check (i.e. testing all combinations).